# Render Top Level Categories as well as ALL Subcategories of a Specific store

Tags: category, multistore, topmenu

I am able to get the list of categories of a current store as menu items using code:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But, how do I get top level categories as well as all subcategories of a specific store using store id? I want to include main store categories as menu items in the second store.

Answer (score 2):

See the file `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Category.php` on `getStoreCategories()` method. You can copy this to your own helper and modify the first line.

```
$parent     = Mage::app()->getStore($your_store_id)->getRootCategoryId();
```

Set `$your_store_id` variable to store_id of your choice.

Comment: I am getting following error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreCategories() on a non-object in app/design/frontend/default/sales_store/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml on line 41`

Comment: I tried to implement it by using `getStoreCategories()` method as you mentioned but I keep getting and error and I am very new to magento so can you give me an example of the code?

Comment: Give me something that I can work with. Where did you get the code above? Did you write this code yourself? If not, which template file is it? What magento version are you using?